# how can I display the logged in user's wall

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api

how can I display the logged in user's wall?
I am able to post on user's wall successfully using Graph API.

Comment: what do you mean by logged in user's wall? do you mean user profile who has logged in? please be specific.

Comment: Thanks for prompt response.Trying to make it more specific.
How can i get username so i can redirect to user facebook page.

Comment: Are you showing wall in your application or redirecting to wall?

Answer (score 0):

Try this fql query. This will give profile_url of logged in user.:

```
string response = fbService.fql.query("select name, profile_url from user where uid = me()");
```